# Getting 3 columns to be responsive

Tags: html, css

I am using a theme with Wordpress and it has some built in column classes that are responsive. I am trying to get a 3 column layout to work properly. The problem is on the initial display. I want the site to have a layout as follows:

```
NAV | BIO AND PIC | SIDEBAR
```

What I get is:

```
BIO AND PIC | SIDEBAR | NAV
```

**HTML Code**

You can see the site at [site in question](http://dev.icsandbox.com/about-us/senior-professionals/james-g-b-demartini/)

**The relevant CSS:**

```
.fusion-column.fusion-two-third {
  width: 65.3333%;
}
dev.icsandbox.com/media="all"
.fusion-column.fusion-one-sixth, .fusion-column.fusion-five-sixth, .fusion-column.fusion-one-fifth, .fusion-column.fusion-two-fifth, .fusion-column.fusion-three-fifth, .fusion-column.fusion-four-fifth, .fusion-column.fusion-one-fourth, .fusion-column.fusion-three-fourth, .fusion-column.fusion-one-third, .fusion-column.fusion-two-third, .fusion-column.fusion-one-half {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 4%;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
body {
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  color: #404040;
  margin: 0px;
  font-family: 'HelveticaNeue';
  font-weight: light;
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 21px;
  letter-space: .4px;
}
body, .post .post-content, .post-content blockquote, #wrapper .fusion-tabs-widget .tab-holder .news-list li .post-holder .meta, .sidebar .jtwt, #wrapper .meta, .review blockquote div, .search input, .project-content .project-info h4, .title-row, .simple-products-slider .price .amount, .quantity .qty, .quantity .minus, .quantity .plus, .timeline-layout h3.timeline-title, .blog-timeline-layout h3.timeline-title, #reviews #comments > h2, .sidebar .widget_nav_menu li, .sidebar .widget_categories li, .sidebar .widget_product_categories li, .sidebar .widget_meta li, .sidebar .widget .recentcomments, .sidebar .widget_recent_entries li, .sidebar .widget_archive li, .sidebar .widget_pages li, .sidebar .widget_links li, .sidebar .widget_layered_nav li, .sidebar .widget_product_categories li {
  color: #404040;
}
body, .sidebar .slide-excerpt h2, .footer-area .slide-excerpt h2, #slidingbar-area .slide-excerpt h2, .post-content blockquote, .review blockquote q {
  line-height: 21px;
}
body, .sidebar .slide-excerpt h2, .footer-area .slide-excerpt h2, #slidingbar-area .slide-excerpt h2, .jtwt .jtwt_tweet, .sidebar .jtwt .jtwt_tweet {
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 23px;
}

#wrapper .fusion-column.last {
  margin-right: 0;
}

.fusion-column.fusion-one-third {
  width: 30.6666%;
}
.fusion-column.fusion-one-sixth, .fusion-column.fusion-five-sixth, .fusion-column.fusion-one-fifth, .fusion-column.fusion-two-fifth, .fusion-column.fusion-three-fifth, .fusion-column.fusion-four-fifth, .fusion-column.fusion-one-fourth, .fusion-column.fusion-three-fourth, .fusion-column.fusion-one-third, .fusion-column.fusion-two-third, .fusion-column.fusion-one-half {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 4%;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

#main .sidebar {
  width: 23%;
}
#main .sidebar {
  background-color: #989898;
}
.sidebar {
  width: 23.4042553%;
  float: right;
}
```

Comment: Please include a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) with only the code necessary to reproduce the issue in your quesiton. Otherwise the question will not be useful in the future when the issue is corrected.

Comment: I added the CSS via an edit to the question

Comment: From what I can see looking at your site, you have to firstly switch the content elements between them (`fusion-two-third` with `fusion-one-third`), then change the class name of `fusion-two-third two_third` to `fusion-one-third one_third` as 1 third and 2 thirds take up the whole width. Then, if you inspect your `DOM` you will see that you have a `<div class="fusion-clearfix'></div>` there.. remove it and you'll have the desired layout.

Comment: Razvan, that gets it almost there. I am still getting:

CONTENT     CONTENT
NAV

I am trying to figure out how to make the NAV come up to the left of the first content column. You can see the link in the question to see the changes working. There is now some space on the right so the nav should fit

Comment: I fixed it. There needed to be a content wrapper around the two content columns. Once I added that everything worked perfectly. Thanks! Razvan if you place your answer as an actual answer I can mark it as correct. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can see looking at your site, you have to firstly switch the content elements between them:

```
.fusion-two-third with .fusion-one-third
```

then change the class name of

```
.fusion-two-third .two_third to .fusion-one-third .one_third
```

as 1 third and 2 thirds take up the whole width. Then, if you inspect your DOM you will see that you have a:

```
<div class="fusion-clearfix'></div>
```

Remove it as this pushes your sidebar under the content and you'll have the desired layout.